# Bad rounding of decimal part during save

Tags: mysql, cakephp, floating-point, save, rounding

My problem is bad rounding of decimal part. I saving data in the loop. Only last updated item is changed incorrectly.
 For example - saved number is 13778.12888 and value in table is 13778,1. Saving: 
`$this->save($data) - debug($data)` shows correct value.

Comment: How have you defined the column in the database?

Comment: FLOAT(11). Antecedent values are correct, only last updated item is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select a column of a floating point type defined as `FLOAT(n)` with n less than 25, MySQL seems to round the output to 6 significant digits, which is definitely surprising. The value is *stored* with the full precision of a IEEE single-precision floating point number though. To get the value with full precision you can use a simple trick like adding 0; check it out:

```
create table numbers (f float(24));
insert into numbers set f = 12345678;
select f from numbers;
-- 12345700
select f + 0 from numbers;
-- 12345678
```

Using the double precision type `FLOAT(53)` you don't get this rounding effect, but it will use twice the storage.

Comment: Thanks. Your advice was helpful.